# Joining stock data together in a loop via quantmod

Tags: r, loops, quantmod

I have been trying to bind together stock data I gather from the **quantmod** package in R, but the package gives back the data in a XTS format, which is kind of hard to turn into a data frame and bind them all together into a single large data frame.

So far I have done this. I understand the logic, I understand what I have to do, I need to create an empty data frame with all the desired columns and then put individual stocks into the data frame, but it's hard to work with the XTS format.

I am also planning on binding together all S&P 500 stocks, which is why I need to do it in a loop and not some other way manually.

```
library(quantmod)

start <- as.Date("2000-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2020-04-15")
symbolBasket <- c('MMM', 'AXP', 'AAPL', 'BA', 'CAT', 'MSFT', 'IBM') 

empty_df <- data.frame(Open= numeric(), 
                       High = numeric(), 
                       Low = numeric(), 
                       Close = numeric(), 
                       Volume = numeric(), 
                       Adjusted = numeric(),
                       Ticker = character())

for (i in symbolBasket) {
  xts <- as.data.frame(getSymbols(i, src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end))

  df <- as.data.frame(xts)
  ticker <- i
  df_with_ticker <- cbind(df,ticker)
  df_final <- rbind(empty_df,df)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be using the built-in function `getSymbols` with the `env =` argument.

We can use a simple `for` loop to extract the data as a `data.frame` from the environment and get the dates out of the rownames. `rbindlist` from `data.table` makes it easy to bind the final results together.

```
library(quantmod)
library(data.table)
stockEnv <- new.env()
getSymbols(symbolBasket, src='yahoo', env=stockEnv, from = start, to = end)
datalist <- list()
for(stock in ls(stockEnv)){
  table <- as.data.frame(stockEnv[[stock]])
  date = rownames(table)
  rownames(table) <- NULL
  colnames(table) <- c("Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adjusted")
  bound.table <- data.frame(Ticker = stock, date ,table)
  datalist[[stock]] <-  bound.table
}
Result <- rbindlist(datalist,fill=TRUE) 
Result
#       Ticker       date       Open       High        Low      Close    Volume   Adjusted
#    1:   AAPL 2000-01-03   3.745536   4.017857   3.631696   3.997768 133949200   3.470226
#    2:   AAPL 2000-01-04   3.866071   3.950893   3.613839   3.660714 128094400   3.177650
#    3:   AAPL 2000-01-05   3.705357   3.948661   3.678571   3.714286 194580400   3.224152
#    4:   AAPL 2000-01-06   3.790179   3.821429   3.392857   3.392857 191993200   2.945139
#    5:   AAPL 2000-01-07   3.446429   3.607143   3.410714   3.553571 115183600   3.084645
#   ---                                                                                   
#35710:   MSFT 2020-04-07 169.589996 170.000000 163.259995 163.490005  62769000 163.490005
#35711:   MSFT 2020-04-08 165.669998 166.669998 163.500000 165.130005  48318200 165.130005
#35712:   MSFT 2020-04-09 166.360001 167.369995 163.330002 165.139999  51431800 165.139999
#35713:   MSFT 2020-04-13 164.350006 165.570007 162.300003 165.509995  41905300 165.509995
#35714:   MSFT 2020-04-14 169.000000 173.750000 168.000000 173.699997  52874300 173.699997
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for loops, you can use tidyquant to get all the stocks. This will return a data.frame with all the data.

```
library(tidyquant)

start <- as.Date("2000-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2020-04-15")
symbolBasket <- c('MMM', 'AXP', 'AAPL', 'BA', 'CAT', 'MSFT', 'IBM') 

result <- tq_get(symbolBasket, from = start, end = end)
result
# A tibble: 35,763 x 8
   symbol date        open  high   low close  volume adjusted
   <chr>  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 MMM    2000-01-03  48.0  48.2  47.0  47.2 2173400     26.3
 2 MMM    2000-01-04  46.4  47.4  45.3  45.3 2713800     25.3
 3 MMM    2000-01-05  45.6  48.1  45.6  46.6 3699400     26.0
 4 MMM    2000-01-06  47.2  51.2  47.2  50.4 5975800     28.1
 5 MMM    2000-01-07  50.6  51.9  50.0  51.4 4101200     28.7
 6 MMM    2000-01-10  50.2  51.8  50    51.1 3863800     28.5
 7 MMM    2000-01-11  50.4  51.2  50.2  50.2 2357600     28.1
 8 MMM    2000-01-12  51.0  51.8  50.4  50.4 2868400     28.1
 9 MMM    2000-01-13  50.7  50.9  50.2  50.4 2244400     28.1
10 MMM    2000-01-14  50.4  50.5  49.5  49.7 2541800     27.7
# ... with 35,753 more rows
```

If you want to do this for the whole SP500, you might want to look into BatchGetSymbols. This can run in parallel if you set the `do.parallel` option to `TRUE`. The [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BatchGetSymbols/vignettes/BatchGetSymbols-vignette.html) show you how to get all the stocks for the SP500.

Comment: Wow, I looked everywhere for more interesting stock market data packages, but never found neither tidyquant or BatchGetSymbols. That actually solves my problem just as well as Ian Campbell 's solution. Thank you!